# Design Pattern for In-Game UI

Tags: c++, opengl, design-patterns, user-interface, sfml

I'm currently developing a game with friends. We are searching for informations about design patterns for User Interface in order to implement a simple UI including: buttons, progress bar (for health, exp, mana, ...), text, views/subviews, and scroll views.

The first goal is to have something simple but working. We are not looking for patterns about making an UI loading from XML/JSON files, we just need information about the inheritance of our classes and their relationship.

While it doesn't matter while we talk about design patterns and algorithms, we develop in C++, using SFML/OpenGL 2.x for rendering.
Any additional information about implementation in C++/OpenGL are welcome :)

**EDIT:** I already know about the common design patterns and the MVC architecture, but I look for a far more simple alternative since our goal is not to recreate Qt or Cocoa.
My question is more about an alternative and how to organize these patterns.

Comment: I recommend toy research Model View Controller (MVC).

Comment: Question is best suited for [gamedev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3617/good-gui-for-opengl) site, and surely was answered (million times): there are zillion ways; I doubt that anyone will want to explain this in English, but there are already explanations in C++: just take source code of several GUI libraries and study/compare to have an idea. Most popular, "classic" libraries are CEGUI and MyGUI, but there are many many more.

Comment: http://www.cg.tuwien.ac.at/courses/RendEng/SemanticSceneGraphPrePrint.pdf 
You basically wants to have a widget based system. widget(a graphical component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you go over this site, it has a great example from "Gang of 4" (look it up)

[great web for design patterns](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns)

and there is also a great tutorial in youtube

http://www.youtube.com/user/derekbanas

Comment: I have the book of these 4 guys describing the common design patterns. The youtube channel have really interesting content in many topics about software development. Thanks for these good links.